# "Unable to generate a URL for the named route

Tags: php, symfony

Ive just started playing with symfony2 and im working on adding url etc.
I cant seem to get my twig template to pick up on my function when passed its name using @Route.
Any ideas why?

Controller:

```
/**
* @Route("/cube/{number}", name="get_cubed")
*/
public function indexAction($number)
{
    $cube = $number * $number * $number;
    return $this->render('NumberCubedBundle:Default:index.html.twig',
        array('number' => $number, 'cube' => $cube)
    );
}
```

My Twig File:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}Cube Number Generator{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    {{ number }}^3 = {{ cube }}
    <a href="{{ path('get_cubed', { 'number': 40 }) }}">Cube 40</a>
{% endblock %}
```

The Error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "get_cubed" as such route does not exist.") in NumberCubedBundle:Default:index.html.twig at line 5.
```

Any help would be massively appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Do you have `use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;` at the start?

Comment: i am using that at the start and its still not picking up, adding the route in the routing.yml file as mentioned in the answer worked. But i dont know why its not working from within the controller..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:** why the annotation didn't work

Most probably you didn't include Sensio's vendor bundle as explained in [annotation routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html) and [sensio framwork **EXTRA** bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/index.html).

The default routing mechanism uses the routing file (routing.yml) which does not need the *extra* bundle.

The routing through annotations, on the other hand, are considered an additional feature that is not always desired and thus has been extracted to a separate and optional bundle.

---

You need to configure the route in the routing file:

```
app/config/routing.yml
```

Define the route `get_cubed` using the [standard Symfony 2 routing syntax](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html).

Much like this:

```
get_cubed:
    path:      /cube/{number}
    defaults:  { _controller: NumberCubedBundle:Default:index }
    requirements:
        number: \d+
```

Now you should be able to get the page with the route:

```
.../app_dev.php/cube/40
```

Comment: Worked a treat thank you! I assumed using the @Route above the function was enough.. im still confused as to wether thats an actual comment or not

Comment: But using `@Route` annotation there is no need to use `routing.yml` too. http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html. He just probably doesn't have this bundle installed.

Comment: In my experience it's better to use a routing file instead of annotations, but both should work.

Comment: Its not really answered my prob of why my @Route wasnt working within the controller. If i cant get that answered i will accept yours. My annotations are not working

Comment: Did you use `use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;` in your controller? See also http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/index.html

Comment: i have included that in my controller file, thats why im at a loss as to why this isnt working

Comment: Have set up the bundle as explained on the two links posted? Have you checked the version of the documentation? Sometimes it happens on that website to read documentation for the wrong version.

Answer (score 4):

The Solution for pattern annotation is:
on app/config/routing.yml  add :

```
tuto_produit_bundle:
    resource: "@ProduitBundle/Controller/"
    type: annotation
    prefix: /cat
```

and o URL:

```
http://localhost/produits/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/cat/{adresse}/{route action}
like http://localhost/vente%20produits/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/cat/categorie/
```